# WPF Custom Binding refresh on RaisePropertyChange()

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm, binding, mvvm-light

I have code to perform language localization. It is based on an XML approach that first reads some XML files during application startup and populate a dictionary with key / value strings for the current language. It also populates a List holding XAML describing each language flag.

It all works great, I can show all loaded XAML flags, change language by clicking a flag and my LocalizationManager object (handling the dictionary) can translate any key to to the localized string for me. Fine so far.

But...I am using MVVM (MVVMLight) and when reading about localization and MVVM most/many people tend to think the localization should be handled by the view. I find code behind to break the concept of MVVM in this case and obviously having a property on the VM for every string on the view to bind to is what I would really like to avoid (that is already working just fine by the way).

So I tried a custom binding class that I call TranslateBinding. It is very simple.

```
class TranslateBinding : System.Windows.Data.Binding
    {
        public TranslateBinding(string key) : base()
        {
            Converter = new TranslationConverter(key);
        }
    }
```

The trick here is that I don't forward the string key (the binding path) to the base ctor. I set the binding's Converter to a custom TranslationConverter object and pass in the key to it instead. The TranslationConverter class will keep the key locally, and for every update of the binding the converter will just use the key to return the localized string from my LocalizationManager based on the currently set language.

This approach means that I can perform the localization / translation completely from XAML in a very clean and short way. The XAML code would look like below, where "Move" would be the key to translate to the local language.

```
<Label Content="{loc:TranslateBinding Move}"/>
```

This works, but only problem I have now is that the TranslateBinding does not refresh immediately when I call `RaisePropertyChanged(null)`

If I navigate away from the current View and then back to the same view again, the value has been updated to reflect the new language though.

So my question is simply, how can I force the custom TranslationBinding to also refresh on a `RaisePropertyChanged(null)` call?
I want all bindings to immediately refresh to retrieve the new localized values, when the language has changed.

Comment: Your `TranslateBinding` does not bind against any binding source (you just invoke `base()`), hence why no updates happen. Try setting the source (and path) of your `TranslateBinding` constructor. Try the following: Use an existing source object with an existing property, which fires property change notifications. The actual type and content of the property doesn't matter at all (as the TranslationConverter will just ignore what is coming from the binding source). (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) The object used as binding source sould be a **single** instance used by all TranslateBinding instances. Whenever language changes, let that object fire a property change notification, which will in turn trigger the TranslateBinding's and let TranslationConverter do its magic...

Comment: Thanks @elgonzo I figured it out as well in the meantime. It worked like a charm. I have looked around for an easy, compressed solution to do localization from pure XAML. This seem to meet all my requirements, the XAML gets very nice, easy and clean.

Comment: I have seen that (and upvoted) :-)

Answer (score 1):

It seems I just had to formulate the question to find the answer.
I just made sure to add a dummy string property on the LocalizationManager.
Then I set the TranslationBinding's source to the LocalizationManager and its Path to the dummy string property. Then it was enough to call RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(DummyString)) in the LocalizationManager as soon as the language change.

Localization could now be performed completely from XAML with no overhead in typing complexity, compared to a "normal" binding to the VM.

```
<Label Content="{loc:TranslateBinding Move}"/>
```